# Verify if a user typed a word from a ReactiveList with Reactive Extension

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveList with keywords. The user can add or remove keyword from that list. The app needs to verify if the user typed one of the keywords.
There was already a similar post but it doesn't take in account a flexible list:
[Using Reactive Extension for certain KeyPress sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501073/using-reactive-extension-for-certain-keypress-sequences)

```
var keyElements = new ReactiveList<KeyElement>();
IObservable<IObservable<int>> rangeToMax = Observable.Merge(keyElements.ItemsAdded, keyElements.ItemsRemoved).Select(obs => Observable.Range(2, keyElements.Select(ke => ke.KeyTrigger.Length).Max()));


IObservable<IObservable<string>> detectedKeyTrigger = rangeToMax
    .Select(n => _keyPressed.Buffer(n, 1))
    .Merge().Where(m => keyElements.Where(ke => ke.KeyTrigger == m).Any());
//Here I want to end up with IObservable<string> instead of IObservable<IObservable<string>>
```

I can get rid of the outer IObservable by reassigning the detectedKeyTrigger each time an element in the reactive list changes, but then I lose all my subscriptions.
So, how can I end up with just an Observable of strings?

Comment: Can you please fix your code? It's either got a bracket extra bracket after the `.Buffer(n, 1)` or after the `.Any())`. Then can you please make a [mcve]? I'd love to be able to compile and run your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for spending time on my question. I did a small update on my example code. Meanwhile, Jon Stødle provided the answer I was looking for.

Comment: No worries. In the future it would be good for you to post a [mcve]. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, both `Max` and `Any` have overloads which takes a selector and a predicate respectively. This negates the need of the `Select`.

Next, I changed the `Observable.Merge` to use the `Changed` property of `ReactiveList` which is the Rx version of `INotifyCollectionChanged`. I also changed the `Select` to produce an `IEnumerable` of `int`s instead; it just felt more Right™.

```
var keyElements = new ReactiveList<KeyElement>();
IObservable<IEnumerable<int>> rangeToMax = keyElements.Changed
    .Select(_ => Enumerable.Range(2, keyElements.Max(keyElement => keyElement.KeyTrigger.Length));


IObservable<IObservable<string>> detectedKeyTrigger = rangeToMax.
    .Select(range => range
        .Select(length => _keyPressed.Buffer(length, 1).Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()))) // 1
        .Merge() // 2
        .Where(m => keyElements.Any(ke => ke.KeyTrigger == m)) // 3
    .Switch(); // 4
```

1. Create an `IObservable<string>` which emits the last `n` characters typed by the user. Create such an observable for each of the possible lengths of an *combo*
2. Merge the observables in the `IEnumerable<IObservable<string>>` into one `Observable<string>`
3. Only let strings which mach one of the `KeyTrigger`s through
4. As `rangeToMax.Select` produces an `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` we use `Switch` to only subscribe to the most recent `IObservable<string>` the `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` produces.